# Why can I create users in rails console but not in my rspec test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I can create users in the console find with:

```
2.0.0-p247 :020 >  User.create(username: 'user30', password: 'abc123', admin: true)                                       
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`username` = BINARY 'user30' LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO `users` (`admin`, `created_at`, `pwd_hashed`, `salt`, `updated_at`, `username`) VALUES (NULL, '2014-07-17 01:34:41', 'd3272da7e3fc0f6e1b035dfb10e6f412ae84fac8', '415066400.06787292634781616', '2014-07-17 01:34:41', 'user30')
   (75.6ms)  COMMIT
 => #<User id: 14, username: "user30", pwd_hashed: "d3272da7e3fc0f6e1b035dfb10e6f412ae84fac8", salt: "415066400.06787292634781616", created_at: "2014-07-17 01:34:41", updated_at: "2014-07-17 01:34:41", admin: nil> 
2.0.0-p247 :021 >  User.create(username: 'user31', password: 'abc123', admin: true)                                       
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (1.4ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`username` = BINARY 'user31' LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO `users` (`admin`, `created_at`, `pwd_hashed`, `salt`, `updated_at`, `username`) VALUES (NULL, '2014-07-17 01:34:46', '1ea5630a3c28b36e714625c4b44f3f951ef16c7a', '416177200.3102826047096757', '2014-07-17 01:34:46', 'user31')
   (77.5ms)  COMMIT
 => #<User id: 15, username: "user31", pwd_hashed: "1ea5630a3c28b36e714625c4b44f3f951ef16c7a", salt: "416177200.3102826047096757", created_at: "2014-07-17 01:34:46", updated_at: "2014-07-17 01:34:46", admin: nil> 
2.0.0-p247 :022 >  User.create(username: 'user32', password: 'abc123', admin: true)                                       
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`username` = BINARY 'user32' LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO `users` (`admin`, `created_at`, `pwd_hashed`, `salt`, `updated_at`, `username`) VALUES (NULL, '2014-07-17 01:34:50', '9aeb6cfcb80f57a08c421999dcfb5ad332317789', '417559200.14647833904112617', '2014-07-17 01:34:50', 'user32')
   (12.0ms)  COMMIT
 => #<User id: 16, username: "user32", pwd_hashed: "9aeb6cfcb80f57a08c421999dcfb5ad332317789", salt: "417559200.14647833904112617", created_at: "2014-07-17 01:34:50", updated_at: "2014-07-17 01:34:50", admin: nil> 
2.0.0-p247 :023 > 

2.0.0-p247 :005 > User.count
   (0.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` 
 => 3
```

but in rspec when I have

```
describe "keep admin" do

  its "Can't delete the only admin" do
    user1 = User.create(username: 'user1', password: 'abc123', admin: true)
    user2 = User.create(username: 'user2', password: 'def456', admin: true)
    user3 = User.create(username: 'user3', password: 'ghi798', admin: true)
    expect(User.where(admin: true).count).to eq 3
  end

end
```

why do I get 0 instead of 3:

```
Failures:

  1) keep admin Can't delete the only admin should eq 3
     Failure/Error: expect(User.where(admin: true).count).to eq 3

       expected: 3
            got: 0

       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:24:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.37602 seconds
5 examples, 1 failure
```

User model:

```
$ cat app/models/user.rb 
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
require 'digest/sha1'
  attr_accessor :password_confirmation
  attr_accessor :admin

  validates_presence_of     :username
  validates_uniqueness_of   :username
  validates_confirmation_of :password
  validate :password_non_blank

  def self.delete_me(user)
    how_many_admins = User.where(admin: true).count
    if how_many_admins > 1
      puts "delete ok!"
      user.delete
    else
      puts "delete not ok!"
    end
  end

  def self.authenticate(name, password)
    user = self.find_by_username(name)
    if user
      expected_password = encrypted_password(password, user.salt)
      if user.pwd_hashed != expected_password
        user = nil
      end
    end
    user
  end
  def password
    @password
  end

  def password=(pwd)
    @password = pwd
    return if pwd.blank?
    create_new_salt
    self.pwd_hashed = User.encrypted_password(self.password, self.salt)
  end

  def is_admin
    admin ? 'Yes' : 'No'
  end

private
  def password_non_blank
    errors.add(:password, "Missing password") if pwd_hashed.blank?
  end

  def create_new_salt
    self.salt = self.object_id.to_s + rand.to_s
  end

  def self.encrypted_password(password, salt)
    string_to_hash = password + "wibble" + salt
    Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(string_to_hash)
  end

end
```

Comment: What does `create!` spit out on the rspec testing?

Comment: Please post your `User` model.

Comment: hmmm, Other than `...` and `rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:17 # keep admin Can't delete the only admin should eq 3` I've posted the output from the rspec command.

Comment: What if you ran `user = User.build(username: 'user1', password: 'abc123', admin: true)` then on the next line `puts user.save!`. You should see something printed out when running the rspec test again.

Comment: In the console or the test?

Comment: both places are giving me `undefined method `build' for #<Class:0x000000025d1c70>`

Comment: @MichaelDurrant did my answer help a fellow Bostonian?

Answer (score 1):

It appears your admin assignment in your create call isn't working.  In your `console` you set `admin: true` in all of your users, yet look at the log:

`User.create(username: 'user30', password: 'abc123', admin: true)`

```
#<User id: 14, username: "user30", pwd_hashed: "d3272da7e3fc0f6e1b035dfb10e6f412ae84fac8", salt: "415066400.06787292634781616", created_at: "2014-07-17 01:34:41", updated_at: "2014-07-17 01:34:41", admin: nil>
```

`admin: nil` is what is being stored.

You're trying to set a ruby boolean value into what I'm guessing is a "string" field in the database? If so, try this:

`User.create(username: 'user30', password: 'abc123', admin: "true")`

Then change your rspec test to:

`expect(User.where(admin: "true").count).to eq(3)`